# MalformedChunkCodingException: Chunked stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, apache-httpclient-4.x, server-sent-events

Enter code here I've implemented an SSE server and client. The server is implemented using `Netty` and the client uses `Apache http client`.

If I send a message at least every 30 seconds it all seems to work fine, but if I do not I will intermittently get this exception:

````
```
 Caused by: org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: Chunked stream ended unexpectedly
    W/System.err( 2879):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:222)
    W/System.err( 2879):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:183)
    W/System.err( 2879):    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:155)
    W/System.err( 2879):    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:159)
    W/System.err( 2879):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:244)
    W/System.err( 2879):    at java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:130)
    W/System.err( 2879):    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:354)
    W/System.err( 2879):    at com.clover.engine.push.SSEConnection$1.call(SSEConnection.java:85)
    W/System.err( 2879):    at com.clover.engine.push.SSEConnection$1.call(SSEConnection.java:79)
    W/System.err( 2879):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```
````

Right now I'm sending a keep alive message every 30 seconds, but I'd prefer to not have to.

Any suggestions on how to prevent this exception from occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this exception was actually haproxy which was closing the socket when it was idle for too long.